# Fstab wont boot while usb drive is plugged in to system

Tags: fstab

I'm Trying to set my installation of Ubuntu Server 20.04 to automatically mount a USB drive to act as a backup destination. However, I have noticed that when I plug in the USB, Fstab fails and the system won't boot. I'm not sure how to edit Fstab, but I tried running this command:

```
sudo blkid | grep /dev/sdf1 | sed -e 's/:.* UUID/;UUID/' -e 's/ TYPE.*//' | while read re; do sed -i "s;$re;" /etc/fstab; done
```

I'm not sure how the file looked before, but this is the fstab now:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c2713101-d0be-4d04-bab5-30046766b610 / ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Comment: when you say the "system won't boot" do you mean ubuntu or the usb?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like umask is not a supported option...

Actually it doesn't:

- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/ext4/ext4.rst
- https://superuser.com/a/837270/809353
- https://superuser.com/a/637171/809353

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `UUID` in `fstab` this is the correct notation:

```
UUID=38dc1d34-6291-4230-a38f-710069bb825f   /               ext4    errors=remount-ro   0       1
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a mountpoint
`mkdir /home/yourusername/mydirectory` - whatever/wherever you want to call it

Insert your USB
In a terminal type `lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,TYPE,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID`
part of the output should be like something like:
**NAME     SIZE TYPE FSTYPE   MOUNTPOINT                   UUID**
sda       30G disk
├─sda1   977M part swap     [SWAP]                       ba7f8262-edb3-434b-8f08-e1e81314a63d
└─sda2    29G part ext4     /                            fdfff53a-b236-45c5-bda8-0287c7a494aa
sr0     1024M rom

locate your usb in the output:

With a text editor like gedit or vi or nano, open up /etc/fstab:
in another terminal type `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`
at the end of that file add a line
`UUID=fdfff53a-b236-45c5-bda8-0287c7a494aa /home/yourusername/mydirectory   ext4    defaults        0   0`

make sure to use the corresponding UUID and FSTYPE(in my case ext4) of your usb from YOUR output, **NOT** the one that's indicated above from my output.

save it and exit.

(if your usb is already inserted)in the terminal type `sudo mount -a`

you should be able to `cd /home/yourusername/mydirectory` and be in the usb.

Comment: @Dash Interwebs I asked what you meant about the system not booting, If you meant ubuntu, then use waltinator's answer first make sure the usb won't try to boot.... and then use my answer to configure the mountpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS boot order.

If one of the partitions on the USB stick has the `boot` flag set, and the BIOS finds it first, the BIOS will try to boot from it. When that fails, there's no fallback.

```
sudo parted -l
```

will show if this is the case. Read `man parted sudo`.